# Question mark on file in intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on the selenium test framework and for this, I had to integrate an executable file into my project (chromedriver).
But there is an icon with a question mark on the file in IntelliJ. The file type is not recognized.
I’m on Linux ubuntu, my browser is chrome.
What did I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chromedriver` is an executable. IntelliJ can't handle this file since it's not a source file, but that doesn't mean you did anything wrong. You don't need to edit this file, just transparently use it.